# With prepositions - relative adverb 'where' vs relative pronoun 'which'

Tags: grammaticality, relative-pronouns, relative-clauses

I enlarge on [3. the shop next to (close to/before/opposite/in front of, etc.) where we live](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/33940/8712). Thanks to user StoneyB's answer, I did read about [(See definition 2) pro-](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pro-)forms [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-form).

> *These are not all so absurd ..., because the spatial relationships are in most cases reciprocal: if the place where you live is ‘opposite’ the shop, the shop is also ‘opposite’ the place where you live. Still, before and in front of inverts the spatial relationship; and in all these cases, you are inverting your topic: instead of a bound relative clause describing where you live relative to the shop, you have a fused relative clause describing where the shop is, relative to where you live.

I understand the differences for prepositions that invert the spatial relationship (ie are NOT 'reflexive'), such as **in front of**, because X **in front of WHERE** we live <=> X fronts where we live, but X **in front of WHICH** we live <=> X lies behind where we live.

Yet what about the prepositions that are 'reflexive', such as **close/opposite to**? I don't understand the problems caused by 'inverting your topic'? I tried to learn about [fused relative clauses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#Fused_relative_constructions).

Answer (score 1):

For this question, you need compare *where* with examples of *which* when it is accompanied by a locative preposition, "*in* which", "*at* which", "*on* which".

One uses a locative pronoun with *which* when one wants to speak about the physical place. One uses *where* when one wants to refer to a location not in concrete terms, as a discrete physical place, but "in the abstract".

> The skyscraper in which she works was erected two years ago.  She takes the elevator to the 125th floor.
>
> The office where she works is very busy.
>
> The street on which he lives is very narrow.
>
> The town where he was born is called Riverton.
>
> The counter at which we sit for lunch has cushioned seats that spin
>   360 degrees.
>
> We often meet for lunch at a diner where the waitresses are nasty but the food is excellent.